# Darboux theorem on monotone function

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity

According to Darboux theorem a function that has a jump discontinuity can not be a derivative of another function,
on the other hand there is a theorem that states :

> $f$ is monotonic $\Rightarrow f$ is integrable

which means that on interval $\left[0,1\right]$:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & x=1\\ 1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} & x \in \left[\ 1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}, 1-
 \frac{1}{2^n}\ \right] \end{cases}$$

is integrable, but it has a jump discontinuity, what am I getting wrong here ?

Comment: The function you constructed is integrable, but it's integral is not differentiable (at least, not everywhere).

Comment: @5xum but it is differentiable on the given interval [0,1], so what is wrong here ?

Comment: No, the integral is not differentiable on the given interval. The function is piecewise linear, but not differentiable on the joints.

Comment: @5xum Thanks, i get it now :)